# Proper service to US government

Tags: civil-procedure, service-of-process, summary-judgment

How serious is it if the defendant files a motion for **summary judgment for improper service** because I sent certified mail after they signed the receipt and responded to it?

**Detailed background**  -  I filed an EEO case in the DC district court against a US government agency and sent certified mail with summons and complaints to the head of the agency, the Attorney General, and the DC court, and all three signed receipt cards were returned.  The US Postal Service delivered it, I got the signed receipts, and I filed them as proof of service.

After receiving the summons, The government filed several motions to dismiss or for summary judgment.   One was a motion for summary judgement for improper service because I (the plaintiff) sent the certified mail.  Everything else was proper.  The case has been open for one year and has several requests for extension and 25 docket documents filed.
It is clear the defendant received the summons and complaint,  read it,  and answered it in the court's ECF system.

**Is this considered by the court as a serious issue or is it just noise by the defense?**